# Regex for inverse group match

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex which returns the opposite of the matched groups.

Probably an example will explain it better.

My regex is:

```
/(\{[\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"]+\})/gui
```

The input text is:

```
{1}2{3}4{5}6{7}
```

Now it matches like this:

[image: Matched groups]

So I end up with `{1}`, `{3}`, `{5}`, `{7}`, but I need to have `2`, `4`, `6`.
How can I negate it, please? I've tried fiddling around with negative look-aheads but couldn't achieve what I wanted.

*Edit: Unfortunately I can't use functions under my current circumstances and I would really like to solve this with a one-step regex, but I'm not sure if it's possible.*

Comment: So, split with this pattern.

Comment: `(?:\{([\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"])+\})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, but I'd like to solve this only using regex, if it is possible. Nice idea though.

Comment: @Tim007 looks like that matches the same; I've tried that.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? PCRE? I see the `/u` modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's in JavaScript, so I guess Perl-ish? You caught me off guard here.

Comment: @Dropout: I swear it is easier to split than write a regex for that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I agree, unfortunately circumstances don't allow me to solve it like that. One-step regex or bust.

Comment: I tried my hand at it but there are a lot of vulnerabilities. Really, it is not possible without `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs as in PCRE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I appreciate your effort. It looks like it is not possible to achieve it without using something else. (see comments in Chris's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

`/[^{](\d*)[^}]/g`

The captured matches are what you're after.

Update:

`/(?!\{)(\d*)(?!\})/g`

This won't capture the braces

https://regex101.com/r/oT9bY4/1

**Update by OP:**

It seems that this question doesn't have a definite one step answer because it is **not possible to achieve simply with a regex**. For more information see the comments to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it also matches the curly braces.

Comment: That's why I said it's the captured stuff (in the brackets) that you're after

Comment: I'll edit it so it doesn't even match the braces if you need that

Comment: That would be awesome, otherwise it doesn't answer the problem. Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible to omit the first `{` without code.

Comment: I've updated, and linked to a different fiddle. The first refiddle site doesn't seem to support this regex.

Comment: What if the braces contain multiple characters, please? Like I had in the question.. `[\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"]+` it's kind of important.. Otherwise it looks that it does the thing..

Comment: Then replace `\d` with whatever matches your characters. Your original regex doesn't really match your example corpus very well

Comment: So it would be `/(?!{)([\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"]+)(?!})/g`

Comment: I think @WiktorStribiżew is right :(. You can still use the original regex and look at the captured groups, rather than the matches.

Comment: Yeah, it looks impossible :( I didn't know if it wasn't only my lack of regex knowledge, but it really looks that it's not possible to do it with one step. I'll leave the question open for a while, if someone comes up with an answer, and after a while I'll edit in to your answer a note that we came to the solution that it's not possible and then accept it. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

since I cant comment jet Ill do it this way.
u where looking for a { then the group then } and you hope to find } group { so chance the brackets around and make the group inside like this
 `\}([\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"])+\{`  
see test of this regex here https://regex101.com/r/lQ9hC5/2 .

Comment: Would that work with odd number of groups of braces?

Comment: if you look at he maches you see that it maches 2 4 and 6 and not {1} {3} {5} {7}

Comment: for odd numbers of groups use this version of it \}([\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"])+\{? this way you dont need the last { on it

Comment: The first sentence of the question states that I'm trying to **match the inverse of matched groups**. Your solution would not only also match the braces, but also wouldn't work with input like `{1}2{3}4{5}6`.

Comment: if u use the regex.Matches you get a list of the maching parts (the parts within the () ) this is not giving you the brackets with it

Comment: But I need it to match only the outsides of the braces. The opposite of what it matched in the question.

Comment: im used to c# there you have `Regex.Matches` and this gives you a list of the found groups. groups you can specifie with the `()` so only the part in the `()` is grouped and given back

Comment: and since this way you start with a `\}` then the match and finishing with a `\{?` the match is outside of the brackets

Comment: But that relies on further manipulation with the output!! You need to pick the groups that you are interested in. The trick is that I have to get the result directly from the regex.

Comment: `Regex.Matches` gives a list of the matches and nothing else so there is already a list of the matches this way. even if you dont anything with it afterwards

Comment: the `+` is on the wrong position I see now use it like this `\}([\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"]+)\{` for a full match of the stuff outside of the braces

Comment: Please stop trying to force through your answer. It doesn't answer the question. I appreciate your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can say that you need to capture

> Any patterns that leading your pattern.

or

> Any patterns that following your pattern.

where your pattern is

```
(\{[\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"]+\})
```

So I got this regex from the above conditions

```
\{[\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"]+\}(.+?)|(.+?)\{[\w\s-\\\/_=*%\'\"]+\}
```

Literally, here's [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aZ7xT0/1)

Note that my regex will capture all text excluding your pattern but you still need to rearrange them according to existing of two capture groups.